# Importing modules into python shell

Tags: python, shell

Im trying to test my files directly from the python shell instead of running it in my .py file. However whenever I import the module and call a function it says NameError: name 'evaluate_essay' is not defined even though it is defined. How do I fix this?

Here is the code for the program:

```
def evaluate_essay(essayFilename):
    fileList= []
    file= open(essayFilename, "r")
    fileList= [file.read().split()]
    file.close()
    longWords=0
    medWords=0
    shortWords=0
    #nested for loop that checks every word in list
    for i in range (len(fileList)):
        for k in range (len(fileList[0])):
            if (len(fileList[0][k])) >= 7:
                longWords += 1
            if 4<=(len(fileList[0][k]))<=6:
                medWords += 1
            if (len(fileList[0][k])) <= 3:
                shortWords += 1
    #if statements that determines level of each essay
    if (longWords) >= (len(fileList[0])/2):
        print ("This is a COLLEGE LEVEL essay")
    elif (longWords)>(medWords) and (longWords)>(shortWords):
        print ("This is a HIGH SCHOOL LEVEL essay")
    elif (medWords)>(longWords) and (medWords)>(shortWords):
        print ("This is a MIDDLE SCHOOL LEVEL essay")
    else:
        print ("This is an ELEMENTARY SCHOOL LEVEL essay")

evaluate_essay()
```

Comment: In order to answer the question fully, we need to know: (1) current working directory that you invoked `python` interpreter in, relative to this file, (2) this file's name,  (3) how you did the import in the python interpreter, (4) how you tried to invoke `evaluate_essay()` in the interpreter.

Comment: after importing your `.py` file, you'll want to prefix the reference to the method with the module name, so something like `import mymodule`, then `mymodule.evaluate_essay('afilename')`

Comment: A likely cause for problems is that you have a naming conflict and you successfully imported some other package whose name collides with your file's.  A less likely cause for problems is that your environment has overwritten `PYTHONPATH` or some other module manipulates `sys.path` before your import.

Comment: 1. the working directory i put the file in is in Documents 2. the files name is problem3.py and i typed in import problem3 in the interpreter and after restating the shell i get a different error saying TypeError evaluate_essay() missing 1 required positional argument: 'essayFilename'

Comment: Did you do `from mymodule import evaluate_essay`?

Comment: I agree with @HåkenLid , in case you do `import mymodule` then the `evaluate_essay` should be called as: `mymodule.evaluate_essay`. If you want to call it without the module name, you should do `from mymodule import evaluate_essay` or `from mymodule import *` in case you need to use other methods defined in there as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, remove the call to `evaluate_essay` from the script, or give it an argument.  You're currently calling it without an argument, but it requires one.

To call this function from an interactive session, you first need to import the module.  One of the following conditions must be met.

1. Your interpreter session is running in the directory containing the module.
2. The module is in a directory that's in your `PYTHONPATH`.

Now, in the interpreter, there are two approaches.  One is to import the module and prefix references to its attributes with its name, like so.

```
import problem3
problem3.evaluate_essay(my_file_name)
```

The other approach is to explicitly import the function and use its name unqualified.

```
from problem3 import evaluate_essay
evaluate_essay(my_file_name)
```